# SQLAlchemy session query with INSERT IGNORE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a bulk insert/update with SQLAlchemy.  Here's a snippet:

```
for od in clist:
    where = and_(Offer.network_id==od['network_id'],
                 Offer.external_id==od['external_id'])
    o = session.query(Offer).filter(where).first()
    if not o:
        o = Offer()
    o.network_id = od['network_id']
    o.external_id = od['external_id']
    o.title = od['title']
    o.updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    payout = od['payout']
    countrylist = od['countries']
    session.add(o)
    session.flush()

    for country in countrylist:
        c = session.query(Country).filter(Country.name==country).first()
        where = and_(OfferPayout.offer_id==o.id, 
                     OfferPayout.country_name==country)
        opayout = session.query(OfferPayout).filter(where).first()
        if not opayout:
            opayout = OfferPayout()
        opayout.offer_id = o.id
        opayout.payout = od['payout']
        if c:
            opayout.country_id = c.id
            opayout.country_name = country
        else:
            opayout.country_id = 0 
            opayout.country_name = country
        session.add(opayout)

    session.flush()
```

It looks like my issue was touched on here, http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg05983.html, but I don't know how to use "textual clauses" with session query objects and couldn't find much (though admittedly I haven't had as much time as I'd like to search).

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and I'd imagine there's some issues in the code besides the fact that it throws an exception on a duplicate key.  For example, doing a flush after every iteration of clist (but I don't know how else to get an the o.id value that is used in the subsequent OfferPayout inserts).

Guidance on any of these issues is very appreciated.

Comment: OK, I realized that the code above is in fact handling the INSERT/UPDATE part and the duplicate key error was being caused by having a unique index on external_id (should've been on network_id,external_id).  Anyway, I'm still curious about how the above can be improved, as the way I'm doing it now feels gross.  I'd also love to hear about using textual clauses with the ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you should be doing these things is with session.merge().

You should also be using your objects relation properties. So the o above should have o.offerpayout and this a list (of objects) and your offerpayout has offerpayout.country property which is the related countries object.

So the above would look something like

```
for od in clist:

    o = Offer()
    o.network_id = od['network_id']
    o.external_id = od['external_id']
    o.title = od['title']
    o.updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    payout = od['payout']
    countrylist = od['countries']

    for country in countrylist:
        opayout = OfferPayout()
        opayout.payout = od['payout']
        country_obj = Country()
        country_obj.name = country
        opayout.country = country_obj

        o.offerpayout.append(opayout)

     session.merge(o)
     session.flush()
```

This should work as long as all the primary keys are correct (i.e the country table has a primary key of name).  [Merge](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/session.html#merging) essentially checks the primary keys and if they are there merges your object with one in the database (it will also cascade down the joins).